# Bloom release failure

Tags: bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can't understand what is wrong when I try to release with bloom:

In my repo https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp
I have done for groovy branch:

```
$ catkin_generate_changelog
$ catkin_tag_changelog
$ catkin_prepare_release
```

that has created the new tag groovy-0.7.4

Then to release this new version to https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp-release I did:

```
$ bloom-release vision_visp --track groovy --rosdistro groovy
...
Everything up-to-date
==> Releasing 'vision_visp' using release track 'groovy'
==> git-bloom-release groovy
Processing release track settings for 'groovy'
Checking upstream devel branch for package.xml(s)
Cloning into '/tmp/tmpePvEhb/upstream'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 3388, done.
remote: Counting objects: 191, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (191/191), done.
remote: Total 3579 (delta 119), reused 3 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3579/3579), 1.35 MiB | 527.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2161/2161), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Looking for packages in 'groovy' branch... found 6 packages.
Detected version '0.7.4' from package(s): ['visp_camera_calibration', 'visp_hand2eye_calibration', 'vision_visp', 'visp_auto_tracker', 'visp_tracker', 'visp_bridge']

Executing release track 'groovy'
==> bloom-export-upstream /tmp/tmpePvEhb/upstream git --tag groovy-0.7.4 --display-uri https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp.git --name upstream --output-dir /tmp/tmpruKz1m
Checking out repository at 'https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp.git' to reference 'groovy-0.7.4'.
Exporting to archive: '/tmp/tmpruKz1m/upstream-groovy-0.7.4.tar.gz'
md5: 746ef2c87d8cd72fc7031992d6e05604

==> git-bloom-import-upstream /tmp/tmpruKz1m/upstream-groovy-0.7.4.tar.gz  --release-version 0.7.4 --replace
The latest upstream tag in the release repository is 'upstream/0.7.3'.
Importing archive into upstream branch...
The package(s) in upstream are version '0.7.3', but the version to be released is '0.7.4', aborting.
<== Error running command '['/usr/bin/git-bloom-import-upstream', '/tmp/tmpruKz1m/upstream-groovy-0.7.4.tar.gz', '--release-version', '0.7.4', '--replace']'
Release failed, exiting.
```

Many thanks if you have some ideas ?

Best regards

Fabien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182464/bloom-release-failure/) by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is:

```
The package(s) in upstream are version '0.7.3', but the version to be released is '0.7.4', aborting.
```

This means that version in the package.xml(s) in the "development branch" do not match the version in the package.xml(s) of the tag it is trying to release.

From you output I can see that the development branch is `groovy`, which looking at your repository has version `0.7.4`:

https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp/blob/groovy/vision_visp/package.xml#L3

Then looking at the output I can see that it is trying to release from the tag `groovy-0.7.4`  which has version `0.7.3` in it's package.xml(s):

https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp/blob/groovy-0.7.4/vision_visp/package.xml#L3

So somehow you have gotten version `0.7.3` tagged as `groovy-0.7.4`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1